# Creating a Day Counter

Tags: python

Does any one know the best way for me to make my PI count the days since an action was performed and display the value every day,

I basically want my pi display to tell me how many days have passed since said action

Comment: What type of action? How will the Pi know this action happened? You haven't given us enough info to even begin answering your question.

Comment: Say when I push a button connected to gpio pins

Comment: Store the time when the button is pushed and with a daily chron job substract it from the current time and show its difference. But this is not a question specific to Raspberry Pi. You should better ask at https://stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

I would use Python, basically loop continually, checking for button press and time to display information. If the button is pressed record the 'lastPress' datetime. If the 'timeToDisplay' is reached then calculate the days.

```
import datetime,time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

buttonBCMPin = 16
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(buttonBCMPin,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP) # GPIO16 -> Button -> Ground

lastPress = None
strTime = '10:00'
timeToDisplay = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.datetime.now().date(),datetime.datetime.strptime(strTime,'%H:%M').time())

while True:
    if GPIO.input(buttonBCMPin) == GPIO.LOW:
        lastPress = datetime.datetime.now()

    if datetime.datetime.now() > timeToDisplay:
        if lastPress == None:
            print('Not yet pressed')
        else:
            print('Last pressed ',(datetime.datetime.now()-lastPress).days,'day(s) ago')
        timeToDisplay = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.datetime.now().date()+datetime.timedelta(days=1),datetime.datetime.strptime(strTime,'%H:%M').time())

    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: This does not answer a question specific to Raspberry Pi. Please have a look at our policies at [How do I write a good answer?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). There you will find "*..avoid trying to answer questions which... are not about raspberry pi as [defined in the help center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)*".